# App Localizar API automaticamente

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

Tenho uma aplicação que faz solicitações a uma API local e preciso que mudar a API de maquina, pois posso usar vários servidores e eles podem ter IPs diferentes. Gostaria de fazer meu app buscar o servidor na rede em que ele estiver automaticamente e estabelecer a conexão. Estou trabalhando com React Native + NodeJS. 
Estou criando a aplicação e gostaria de saber se existe algum padrão já estabelecido que poderia usar para fazer essa localização do servidor.

Comment: Todos os servidores estão na mesma rede? Não é possível usar um servidor com IP fixo e, a partir dele, redirecionar as requisições?

Comment: Não. Os servidores são em redes diferentes. O problema é que a solução será usada em clientes diferentes e cada um usa um IP para o servidor. Daqui queria achar uma forma de não ter que colocar o IP do servidor manualmente na aplicação e sim buscar por um servidor. Algo como um apelido ou busca automática.